# Broke my conda install of pyqt, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, conda

I was trying to run a script found on github when I ran into an error : QtMultimedia couldn't be found.
I thought maybe if I pip installed PyQT5 (latest version) it would fix my problem. Except it didn't and when I uninstalled it again, my install previously working install isn't anymore. I can import PyQT5 but none of the modules are found : for example PyQT5.QtCore can't be found. 
What should I do to make my install work again ?

Comment: Delete the environment and make a new one, if that doesn't work then just reinstalling Conda is probably the easiest and safest solution.

Comment: @AMC Problem is that's on my root environment... What I did for now is I create a conda venv just for pyqt which made it work again on that env. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: _Problem is that's on my root environment..._ Yeah, reinstalling Conda is the right move here.

Comment: @AMC Do you have any good resource or advice on how to remove it cleanly and fully ?

Comment: The standard uninstallation procedure should be fine. You can always manually search for and remove any files which include "conda" and "anaconda" afterwards.